# input type number fail's with zero

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the below `input` field and a `ng-change` function, which when triggered is failing when the number starts with zero.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="num" ng-change="confirm(num, 9)" />

function confirm = function(value, length) {
   if (!value) return false;
   $scope.val =  ("" + value).length !== length;
};
```

The below number when i enter is failing `"011111111"`

Comment: That's because decimal numbers *can't* start with 0. You're typing 0 but the actual value is being set to `11111111`.

Comment: parse the number and then try

Comment: When numbers have a leading 0 in JS, it's assumed they are octal, not decimal I believe. If you want this comparison, use a string. Open your console, type `011111111` and you'll get `2396745` as a result

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically speaking, numbers cannot have leading zeros. In JS, Putting a leading 0 on an integer is the equivalent to parsing octal, or base 8.

```
var num = 011111111;
//is the same as
parseInt(011111111, 8);
//equals 2396745
```

When in reality you want a decimal parse, which is base 10. To keep your leading zero, you'll have to make sure the input is a string, or remove it and do your own parsing to add it in there if detected.

Comment: should i use parseInt(num, 10) or base 8

Comment: You can't parse a number with a leading 0. `parseInt(num,10)` will still parse an octal number to decimal which doesn't change anything. You need string manipulation.

Comment: I can't change the type to text... coz it removes the zero on pressing back button... is there any other way